# Which C standard (ANSI, c99...) does my Clang compiler adopt?

Tags: c, clang

How can I know which C standard my current Clang compiler adopts? The version of the compiler is shown below:

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I read that

> Clang 3.3 and later implement all of the ISO C++ 2011 standard. By
>   default, Clang builds C++ code according to the C++98 standard, with
>   many C++11 features accepted as extensions.

But these are talking about C++ standard. I am concerned with which C standard (Ansi, C99 etc) my Clang compiler is using.

Comment: `printf("%ld\n", __STDC_VERSION__);` can help

Comment: @Lundin I am not sure that is good dupe. It has no mention of clang.

Comment: @user694733 It isn't compiler-specific, you can check this by using standard C.

Comment: @Lundin Perhaps you are right. I first read the question as *"What C standards my compiler supports?"*, while question is more like *"What C standard does my compiler use by default?"*, in which case the duplicate works.